# Do the people in the table satisfy the following condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, count

I have the following tables:

**Student Table**

```
| id | name     | gender|
|----|----------|-------|
| 1  | April    |  F    |
| 2  | Jane     |  F    |
| 3  | Joe      |  M    |
| 4  | Mike     |  M    |
```

**Project Table**

```
| project_id | student_id | project_name|
|------------|------------|-------------|
| 101        | 1          |  Alpha      |
| 101        | 2          |  Alpha      |
| 101        | 3          |  Alpha      |
| 102        | 2          |  M          |
| 102        | 4          |  M          |
| 103        | 1          |  Beta       |
| 103        | 3          |  Beta       |
```

Assume there are much more students and project ids.
Multiple students can work in the same project.

My question is, having the tables above, how can I check how many students who worked together on 2 or more projects? So in the example above, students with id 1 and 3 worked together in project Alpha and Beta.

My code so far is

```
SELECT * FROM student s
JOIN project s ON student.id = project.project_id
```

I know I want to join both tables by the column they share (which is the student id) but I have no idea what to do after. I am new to SQL barely a week in learning and would appreciate the most help.

Comment: The redundancy in `projects` indicates you're missing a table. Unless students get to have different names for the same project, you should have separate `projects` table to hold information about a project, and a join table between students and projects.

Answer (score 1):

Use a self join and aggregation:

```
select p1.student_id, p2.student_id, count(*) as num_projects
from projects p1 join
     projects p2
     on p1.project_id = p2.project_id and
        p1.student_id < p2.student_id
group by p1.student_id, p2.student_id
having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select 1
    from projects p1
    inner join projects p2 
        on p2.project_id = p1.project_id and p2.student_id < p1.student_id
    group by p1.student_id, p2.student_id
    having count(*) > 1
) t
```

The inner query self-joins the project table and generates unique tuples of students that worked on the same project; the `having` clause filters on tuples that worked together on more than one project.

The outer query just counts the number of tuples.